# Manually change datafile size or let oracle do the job during schema duplication

Tags: oracle

I have to duplicate a (relative) big schema inside the same database (using impdmp). I know Oracle will automaticaly enlarge the data file during the import.

What is the right way : let Oracle automatically enlarge the file or enlarge it manually before the import ?

Answer (score 1):

it depends.

If you absolutely want to make sure your import does not fail on space problems -> pre-alloc the space.

If your import is part of a reorganisation job where you would try to win back space -> let the database grow when needed and start small.

If performance is an issue, make sure that table spaces that will become huge, also grow in big steps so the dynamic growth does not slow the import too often.

Comment: Thansk. In term of performance, is it best to let Oracle do the automatic extend or prepare the tablespace in advance to avoid multiples automatic extensions ?

Comment: dynamic extensions will slow a little bit. Make sure that the growth parameters fit the expected grow pattern of the table space. growing with 64KB steps for a table space that grows to TB's is a pain. Make bigger steps and prepare enough datafiles.  In the end, the pre-alloc also takes time. So if you want the minimal execution time then preallocate.